# KURA : how to receive MQTT messages using the DataService?

Tags: osgi, mqtt, osgi-bundle, kura

How can I receive the MQTT messages published on a specific topic?
I can publish messages on the MQTT broker but I dont know how to receive messages?

Here is my component xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" activate="activate" deactivate="deactivate" name="arduinoCommunicator">
   <implementation class="arduinoCommunicator.ArduinoCommunicator"/>
   <reference bind="setDataService" cardinality="1..1" interface="org.eclipse.kura.data.DataService" name="DataService" policy="static" unbind="unsetDataService"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="org.eclipse.kura.data.DataServiceListener"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

Here is my bundle activator class, I only kept the needed code, I implement the DataServiceListener, I subscribe to the topic on the onConnectionEstablished() and I imagine that I got the message on the function onMessageArrived, the problem is I don't see the logs that the subscription has been made and the function onMessageArrived() is not executed:

```
public class ArduinoCommunicator implements DataServiceListener {
public static DataService dataService; 


@Override
public void onConnectionEstablished() {
    String topic="egmkey/device2/cmd/PING";
    System.out.println("connection has been established");
    try {
        ArduinoCommunicator.dataService.subscribe(topic, 1);//egmkey/device2/cmd/PING
        System.out.println("subscription done to topic"+topic);
    } catch (KuraException e) {
        System.out.println("failed to subscribe: "+ e);
    }
}

@Override
    public void onMessageArrived(String topic, byte[] payload, int qos, boolean retained) {
        System.out.println("message received!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:"+topic);

    }

}
```

What have I missed to be able to receive MQTT messages using DataService on KURA? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly injecting the DataService service into your component. The code below should be closer to what you actually need:

```
public class ArduinoCommunicator implements DataServiceListener {
    public DataService dataService;

    protected setDataService(DataService dataService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionEstablished() {
        String topic = "egmkey/device2/cmd/PING";
        System.out.println("connection has been established");
        try {
            dataService.subscribe(topic, 1);//egmkey/device2/cmd/PING
            System.out.println("subscription done to topic" + topic);
        } catch (KuraException e) {
            System.out.println("failed to subscribe: " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageArrived(String topic, byte[] payload, int qos, boolean retained) {
        System.out.println("message received!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:" + topic);

    }

}
```